# Paypal shopping cart integration

Tags: php, paypal, shopping-cart

I am trying to integrate shopping cart to paypal and my application is in PHP.The Form is submitting on paypal correctly with all the parameters but at the time of returning the response when I am trying to print the POST array,it is blank.Can someone please help me that in what form will I be able to get the transaction id and other parameters returned by paypal.

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: the code samples on paypal's site are actully very good

Comment: Could you please share the link?

Comment: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-code-samples

Answer (score 0):

paypal return the data in get array as query parameter..so use $_GET.

Answer (score 0):

is this paypal ipn?
if yes, there is a **procedure** you should follow, not a one-way call.

Comment: No i am not using paypal ipn.